# Iterating a Talend job based on a condition

Tags: postgresql, etl, talend

I have a control table in my PostgreSQL Database. Some sample data is shown below:

```
id    section_code    ddu_area    ddu_action    status_flag
1     4636            1           1             0
2     4636            1           2             0
3     4636            2           1             0
4     4636            2           2             0
```

I have few staging tables of each of the ddu_area's. There are a total 5 distinct ddu_areas. I want to pass the one id at a time and execute my ETL and id to be passed should have the status_flag as 0. When the status_flag is 1, it should take that particular id and pass it to the ETL job and take the data from staging to target.

I don't know whether we have this functionality in Talend or not. I am new to Talend. In SSIS, we can do this using For Each Loop container. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use tFlowToIterate component to iterate over each record after that use tRunJob component to pass the parameters using various way you can see some of them [here](http://dwetl.com/2015/04/03/passing-value-from-the-parent-job-to-the-child-job/)

your job flow should be like this.

```
tFlowToIterate--if----tRunJob
```